# Rhyme of the century!

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, rhyme, anagram

*This puzzle is part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge - ["Unconventional Tag Fusion"](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1).*

> I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,
>   Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve.
>   I keep my five best friends close,
>   I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.
>   You can skip me, I never have to be seen,
>   I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!
>   I guess my story is making you weep,
>   Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

Caution - Follow the rhyme and reach your destination!

Note - I was unsure and out of tags, may be "enigmatic-puzzle" and "pattern" fits in as well. And off-course, its an easier one and won't take you on a long ride. Enjoy!

Hints

> Okay two hints. Line number 5 & 7 in the rhyme are useless. Just added to make the lines rhyme.

More Hints

Well, even I don't like my puzzles to remain unsolvable so here goes another hint. Hope its not a dead give away.

> Line 1 is more of a lateral thinking + enigmatic.
>  Line 2 is again little bit of geometry+enigmatic+lateral+anagram.
>  Line 3 is  lateral thinking.
>  ...to be continued lated

Another hint(As requested in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48219/rhyme-of-the-century)) -

> Line 4 is steganography+lateral thinking
>  Line 6 is anagram
>  Line 8 is lateral thinking(fact)

Another quick hint

> [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram) applies only to "Moil" on line 2, and to "A Housed Tin" on line 6. These words should be rearranged to find a sequence of **letters** that do not (necessarily) form words. Each of these letter sequences is a new clue.

Another one

> Its a non-living thing. We use its like all the time.

Yet another hint

> It's computer related.

Okay another one (I wish I could take away the frustration)

> You need to look down to find the answer. If you are not still sure, ***right below your finger tips.***

Comment: This poem sure makes me think of [(shhh)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_telescopes "space telescopes"), [(psst)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_mission "interplanetary missions") and [(mmm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon "lunar missions"), but so do most poems

Comment: @humn - There you go out in the stars. :) Well, I have kept it to earth for now. So no worries.

Comment: Thanks for the guardrail. I can stop counting on a heavenly answer and go back to counting on my toes.

Comment: Lol. Yeah. Now you can. :D

Comment: I cannot believe this has not been answered yet! It is driving me up the wall. I am dying to know the answer......... Can we have another clue please?

Comment: @PaulD - Here is the first clue.

Comment: Every time I think I'm getting somewhere, the "fantastic car" line throws me off!

Comment: @Paul Without giving any spoilers at all, how much do you think you've managed to solve?

Comment: Do you actually believe that "seen" and "tin" rhyme?   And "close" (as an adjective) and "hoes"?  And how is "the ones who hoes" grammatical?

Comment: I don't think I have any solutions at all yet. @Peregrine Rook, that is very true, and interesting. In fact looking at Techidiot's previous puzzles has got me rethinking the whole thing.

Comment: @CipherRiddle 24 - I have a great answer for line 3, that fits (sort of) with 1 and 2, and line 5 although that apparently is not relevant, and was born (observed, found) in a leap year for line 8. But 'a housed tin' or 'fantastic car for ones who hoes' is completely off the chart for me.

Comment: Is it frowned upon to post guesses in the comments? Because I have a thought but it's based on most of the riddle being insanity...

Comment: I was wondering that too. Especially as there is no mechanism for group work on a solution to a difficult or intractable puzzle like this.

Comment: Would The Sphinx's Lair be an appropriate place for solution collaboration?

Comment: can't we post as Partial answers as we do in other questions ?

Comment: @Sikorski- Yes you can. Also, here is a room if anyone needs any information/clarifications - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/48219/rhyme-of-the-century?tab=general

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's

> Dvorak keyboard layout

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,

> (Author's note): Letter "I" won't be next to letter "O" which is true in case of a normal QWERTY keyboard.

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve.

> (Author's note): "MOIL," which is formed of "IOL,M" won't form a parabola which is formed on a normal QWERTY keyboard.

I keep my five best friends close,

> 5 vowels close together on the home row right next to each other.

I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.

> (Author's note): Letters "BMW" together in the bottom row

You can skip me, I never have to be seen,

> Stick to QWERTY and never see Dvorak

I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!

> "A Housed Tin" is made of the keys on the home row

I guess my story is making you weep,
Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

> Layout was completed in the year 1932 which is a leap year

Comment: Fantastic! I am so glad the answer was an answer that immediately made sense. Thank you. This has been tormenting me for so long.

Comment: Thanks! I did take quite a bit of prodding from the author to finally get there.

Comment: Man, I considered everything from Oregon to the Kingwood Country Club. Glad it's finally answered because I never would've thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is ...

> the Apple Macintosh.

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,

> No idea. Maybe because the "Macintosh" no longer exists, all the current models are named differently.

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve.

> No idea.

I keep my five best friends close,

> Nope

I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.

> [**This beautiful thing right here.**](http://www.cultofmac.com/216676/in-1980-apple-made-a-porsche-into-an-actual-icar/)

You can skip me, I never have to be seen,
I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!

> ADEHINOSTU.  Yeah, not a clue.

I guess my story is making you weep,
Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

> Mac was made in 1984, a leap year.

Best I got for now.  This puzzle is driving me crazy. :)

Comment: +1 for the attempt. But unfortunately no. Not the answer. You knew it as well I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be a

> SMPS

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,

> I've only seen them in desktops.

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve.

> No idea

I keep my five best friends close,

> It has 5 major parts. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply)

I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.

> Fan. SMPS has a fan.

You can skip me, I never have to be seen,

> Skip this line as given in the hint.

I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!

> No idea.

I guess my story is making you weep,
Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

> Introduced in 1980 or 1936 (older and the developed version). Both are leap years either way.

Answer (score 2):

I say..

> Mouse

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,

> Laptops are now used nowadays, where there is no explicit mouse

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve

> No idea

I keep my five best friends close

> Keyboard,UPS,CPU and monitor (fifth might be a printer)

I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.
You can skip me, I never have to be seen,

> Fantastic car might refer to the continuous movement of the mouse...

I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!
I guess my story is making you weep,

> House becomes Mouse with a 'M'agician

Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

> Computer mouse was invented in 1964(A leap year)

Comment: Oh no. Too much of lateral thinking here. :D Though +1 for the try.

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL ANSWER

My working assumption is that the answer to this riddle is

> Oxygen

Discovered in

> 1776

Which is a leap year.

My (very crude) reasoning is as follows:

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe

> If we don't look deeply, the letter which stands out is 'O'

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve

> I haven't yet deduced the meaning of "Moil", but my suspicion is that the "parabola curve" may allude to the letter 'X'

I keep my five best friends close

> My first thought here was a hand or a fist. But, if we're searching for letters, then the five best friends would be the vowels, and the sixth friend would be 'Y'

That's all I have so far, and I do realise it's quite cobbled together.

Comment: I sincerely apologise that this answer is so half-baked

Comment: Didn't made any much sense but +1 for try :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Tesla

I won't be found next if you deeply Observe,

> Tesla is a unit of measurement for magnetic field strength. Not observable.

Moil, won't help to form a parabola curve.

> "MOIL" -->  LIM 0. At limit 0, magnetic field lines do not form a parabola.

I keep my five best friends close,

> This is the one line which makes me doubt Tesla being the right answer. Unless it has something to do with earth's magnetic field.

I even have a fantastic car for the one who hoes.

> Tesla Motors

You can skip me, I never have to be seen,
I am magician who can easily make "A Housed Tin"!

> Tesla's demonstrations were touted to be like 'magic'.  Anagram to compare with Houdini(?)

I guess my story is making you weep,
Another tragedy is, I was born in a year which was leap.

> Nikolas Tesla was born in 1856, a leap year.

I apologise... if this is way off the mark.

Comment: Again, not much sense. But +1 for try.